# Find the last two digits of number $x_{2013}$ where $x_n=9^{x_{n-1}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Let $x_1  = 9$ and the n-th term of the sequence is generated by this rule  $\
x_n  = 9^{x_{n - 1} } 
\
$.

Task : Find the last two digits of the number $\
x_{2013} 
\
$. 
I already solved the problem, but I'm interested in a more elegant take on the matter at hand. Any ideas ?

Comment: Well, if you don't reveal your solution, how can any of us know whether our personal solution is more or less elegant than yours?

Comment: I think you're looking for $$9^{9} \pmod {100}$$

Comment: @Victor ..... 8,9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=x_{2012}$ and $b=x_{2013}$. We have $b=(-1+10)^a$. By the Binomial Theorem $b$ is congruent to $-1+10a$ modulo $100$. But $a$ is congruent to $9$ modulo $10$. It follows that $b$ is congruent to $89$ modulo $100$.

**Remark:** One could excise congruence notation. The last two digits of $b$ are the same as the last two digits of $-1+10a$. But $a$ has last digit  $9$, so is of the shape $10k+9$. It follows that the last two digits of $b$ are the same as the last two digits of $-1+10(10k+9)$,